# How to stop SSH working with removed private key

Tags: ssh

On Ubuntu 14.04 I have a private key in:

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I have installed the public key on the server I wish to connect to and indeed when I run the following, I do connect as expected:

```
ssh me@my-server-ip.com
```

I then deleted the private key on the client but running the above command still connects me. This leads me to believe that the SSH binary is running in some kind of daemon mode wherein it is caching the private key in memory? Is that correct? Short of a reboot, how do I 'flush' SSH to stop using the private key. Thanks

Comment: This question might do a bit better on [su]

Answer (score 7):

Run the following command after removing `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

```
ssh-add -D
```

This commando removes all cached ssh identities from the `ssh-agent`.

If you type `ssh me@my-server-ip.com` now, the password prompt will show.

You can check with `ssh-add -L` what identities the `ssh-agent` has cached.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a little late to this party, but for the enlightenment of others...

It sounds like you have your private SSH key (identity) cached in ssh-agent. Now it is worth noting that ssh-agent does not retain the key cache over a reboot or logout/login cycle, although some systems depending on configuration may add your key during either of those processes. However, in your instance, a reboot or possibly a logout/login cycle would remove the private key from the agent's cache. This is because you have already removed the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file and it therefore cannot be re-initialized into the agent.

For everyone else who may not have yet deleted their `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file(s) or if you don't want to reboot or logout/in right now the following should prove useful.

First, you will want to remove any `~user/.ssh/id_rsa` files which you wish to no longer be cached by ssh-agent.

Next, verify that there are, in fact, identities still being held open in 'ssh-agent' by running the following command:

`ssh-add -L`

This will list the public key parameters of all identities that the agent has actively cached. (Note: `ssh-add -l` will instead list the fingerprints of all keys/identities that are actively cached.)  For each that you would like to remove you should run the following:

`ssh-add -d /path/to/matching/public/key/file`

If you just want to clear out ALL keys/identities from the agent then run this instead:

`ssh-add -D`

At this point, the key(s) desired to be removed will be no longer accessible to the agent and with the actual identity file removed,  there shouldn't' be any way possible for an attempted remote SSH connection with that user to connect without using a different authorization method if configured/allowed.