# id_rsa and id_rsa.pub deleted and still getting access to the server

Tags: ssh

How is it possible that I am still able to connect to the server although I've generated new rsa keys? Even after deleting them, I am still getting access to the server.
The client I am connecting from is Debian 10.

In the log I see the following:
Will attempt key: home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa

And I also see:
Will attempt key: user_name@user_notebook

And that's where it's still getting the key from, even if I delete ~/.ssh/id_rsa and ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.

How can I ensure that the only source for the rsa key is ~/.ssh/id_rsa?

Answer (score 0):

`ssh -i /path/to/id_rsa user@server.domain.com`

Also you can edit you config file as such

```
Host server.domain.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

Answer (score -1):

The key was probably cached by the ssh-agent. You'll have to clear it there after having deleted the id files.
See [How to stop SSH working with removed private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191125/how-to-stop-ssh-working-with-removed-private-key) for details.